# git - problem creating a merge request from command line

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to be able to perform a merge request from my local repo and branch to the master in gitlab, but I cannot get it to work. For some background,

I have a local repo I cloned from this:

```
https://gitlab.com/blah/blahProject
```

I created a feature branch:

```
C:\Users\tclotworthy\thurs\blahProject> git status
On branch feature/timc-blahProject
```

Here are all the branches:

```
 C:\Users\tclotworthy\thurs\blahProject> git branch -a
* feature/timc-blahProject
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

I made my code updates, and committed:

```
C:\Users\tclotworthy\thurs\blahProject> git commit -am "Initial commit of feature/timc-blahProject branch"
[feature/timc-blahProject 68ce284] Initial commit of feature/timc-blahProject branch
Committer: Tim Clotworthy <tclotworthy@blah.com>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
your configuration file:

    git config --global --edit

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author
10 files changed, 649 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 SOLUTION.md
create mode 100644 pom.xml
create mode 100644 src/main/java/blahProject/SatApplication.java
create mode 100644 src/main/java/blahProject/input/FileLoader.java
create mode 100644 src/main/java/blahProject/model/SatelliteConstants.java
create mode 100644 src/main/java/blahProject/model/SatelliteStatus.java
create mode 100644 src/main/java/blahProject/model/SensorReading.java
create mode 100644 src/main/resources/SensorData.txt
create mode 100644 src/test/java/SatAppTest.java
```

At this point I attempted to create the merge request, but got an error:

```
C:\Users\tclotworthy\thur\blahProject> git push -o merge_request.create
fatal: The current branch feature/timc-blahProject has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

   git push --set-upstream origin feature/timc-blahProject

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.
```

So I did what I thought they were suggesting and ran:

```
C:\Users\tclotworthy\thursday\blahProject> git push --set-upstream origin feature/timc-blahProject
remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/blah/blahProject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am not a git expert, and I am struggling for figure out how to address my issue. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you

Comment: The remote says you're not allowed. This is likely an authentication issue, not a git one.

Comment: You can't merge to another's repository directly, instead fork the repo and commit on them, later create a pr.

Comment: @geeky01adarsh ok. How do I fork at this point? Do I switch back to master branch (git checkout master), and then create the fork from there, or do I have to start all over (i.e., fork directly from gitlab rather than cloning from gitlab)? Thank you

Comment: @geeky01adarsh thanks. I figured it out thanks to your clue. I should have forked from the start rather than clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I should have forked from the source project in the first place, rather than clone. Here is the basic rule of thumb:

If you need to create a merge request against an external repo, you cannot start from a clone of that repo, because you will not have permission to write against it. Instead, you need to fork the repo.

I did this directly in gitlab:

1. go to source project
2. click fork button
3. update your new forked project with your changes
4. the merge request button appears the moment those changes are committed
5. create merge request

Here is a link for how to fork:

[how to fork a gitlab repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)